# Hadoop "Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main"

Tags: java, bash, hadoop, cygwin

Before my question is closed as a duplicate: I have looked at all other related questions but the solutions provided don't work for me, probably because I'm using Cygwin, not Unix.

I'm trying out the tuturial [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0). Whenever I run the command (while in c:/hadoop) `bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java`, I get the error `Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main`.

My `Java_Home` variable is set to: `c:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_17` (`echo $JAVA_HOME` confirms this), and my `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` to `c:/PROGRA~1/Java/jdk1.7.0_17/lib/tools.jar`.

`javac -version` confirms that I'm using jdk1.7.0_17.

Would anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: How are you running handoop (the command)? If you are using something like: java -jar ... are you using -cp to specify the other dependencies?

Comment: @pringi I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I'm running the hadoop command as specified above: `bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java` (so without any additional flags). Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the Java binary invoked is the JDK one and not the system wide JRE one?

Comment: A good debugging tool is to print out all system properties and environment variables.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen How can I do that? I am sure that `$Java_home` returns the correct folder, but are there other properties/environment variables that I should look at?

Comment: Are you sure that the file `tools.jar` actually exists at that path?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes, I have checked.

Comment: Verify if you exported all of the following:export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar

Comment: @pringi Yes, all of them are in my `.bashrc` and show up when I expand them using e.g. `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH`...

Comment: I think your problem may be that Hadoop for unix/linux expects the classpath to be colon separated, which means it doesn't like `c:` paths.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ah, that's a good point! Let me try. So annoying those differnces between Windows and Unix, I keep forgetting...

Comment: @RealSkeptic That was it! Thanks a lot - kind of trivial in the end! I'll accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: @dreamer It wasn't exactly an answer, as I didn't offer any solution (not actually knowing what that would be). Perhaps you should self-answer.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I just changed `c:/` to `/cygdrive/c/`. Feel free to post it, you deserve the points ;)!

Comment: Write a small Java program and invoke that instead of Mainc through your mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the differences between Windows and Unix/Linux tools is the handling of `PATH` and `CLASSPATH` variables, where in Windows, to support the `C:\...` path notation, the delimiter in `PATH` and `CLASSPATH` is a semicolon `;`, and on Linux, where `:` in file paths is very rare, the delimiter is `:`.

As you are running on cygwin, you are using the Unix/Linux version of Hadoop (and probably Java as well). This means it is probably expecting `CLASSPATH` to be colon (`:`) delimited.

So you should use the "Unix" version of the path you have given, which in cygwin is available by replacing the `c:` with `/cygdrive/c`.